# Unable to access nested object from JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have the following function component in React:

```
function GetData() {
  const [randomDataJSON, setRandomDataJSON] = useState('');
  const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

  const getData = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${url}`)
      .then((results) => {
        const userData = results.data.results;
        setRandomDataJSON(JSON.stringify(userData, null, 2));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>GetData Component</h3>
      <pre>{randomDataJSON[0].name.first}</pre>
      <button onClick={getData}>Get Data</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default GetData;
```

The JSON data from the API is as follow:

```
[
  {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "title": "Miss",
      "first": "Barbara",
      "last": "Sullivan"
    }, 
...
```

I would like to access and display the `first name` of the JSON data from the API by using `{randomDataJSON[0].name.first` in the `<pre>` tag. However, I keep getting the following error message: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

Comment: it seems the problem is in you state const [randomDataJSON, setRandomDataJSON] = useState(''); it should be const [randomDataJSON, setRandomDataJSON] = useState([]); the default state should be an array not a string. try it out. also try to see what is the content in the response from axios.

Comment: @BobWhite, I don't think there is requirements for default value in react. Also don't think there is a need for `useEffect` there.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting json string to `randomDataJSON` state variable, and trying use JSON string as an object. You can try to `console.log(randomDataJSON)` to confirm my suspicions.

I think you should not convert your data object to json in first place, so `setRandomDataJSON(JSON.stringify(userData, null, 2));` will be `setRandomDataJSON(userData)`;

```
function GetData() {
  const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState('');
  const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

  const getData = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${url}`)
      .then((results) => {
        const userData = results.data.results;
        setRandomData(userData, null, 2);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>GetData Component</h3>
      <pre>{randomData[0].name.first}</pre>
      <button onClick={getData}>Get Data</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default GetData;
```

Comment: you should not set string because you have to parse reverse in order to use as object

Comment: @BobWhite, in post question he is using `JSON.stringify`, which is converting object to string. Axios on the other hand is automatically converting json response to javascript object. So I believe there is no need for either `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify`

Comment: yep, but it should be that way.  json.stringify should be removed. I think the request is waiting for json response. just save the response to state as an array then use it.

Comment: @BobWhite, well, isn't that what I have said in my answer?

Comment: yep complete the answer with a complete code just to clarify to @james

Comment: @BobWhite, ok, good point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238722/discussion-between-aidonline01-and-bob-white).

Answer (score 0):

At the time the page loads axios wouldn't have ran to request the array so randomDataJSON is a string at that time. You could do

```
const [randomDataJSON, setRandomDataJSON] = useState([]);
```

Above you set it to an empty array then check if it has length

```
<pre>{randomDataJSON.length > 0 && randomDataJSON[0].name.first}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to everyone pointing me in the right direction. My new code is as follow. My problem was I didn't know React doesn't allow you to render Javascript Object. To fix this, I just use the map() method to map through the data and display the properties in the object.

```
function GetData() {
  const [randomDataJSON, setRandomDataJSON] = useState([]);
  const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

  const getData = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${url}`)
      .then((results) => {
        const userData = results.data.results;
        setRandomDataJSON(userData);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  console.log('It is an', typeof randomDataJSON);
  console.log('randomDataJSON is ', randomDataJSON);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>GetData Component</h3>
      {randomDataJSON.map((data) => {
        return <p>{data.name.first}</p>;
      })}
      <button onClick={getData}>Get Data</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default GetData;
```